# how to fix fullCalendar

Tags: laravel

Non-static method MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Calendar::addEvents() should not be called statically
I tried to use 
* `composer dump-autoload`
* `php artisan cache:clear`
* `php artisan config:clear`
did not help

EventsController.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Event;
use MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Calendar;


class EventsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $events = Event::get();
        $event_list = [];
        foreach ($events as $key => $event) {
            $event_list[] = Calendar::event(
                $event->event_name,
                true,
                new \DateTime($event->start_date),
                new \DateTime($event->end_date.' +1 day')
            );
        }
        $calendar_details = Calendar::addEvents($event_list);

        return view('events', compact('calendar_details') );
    }
```

Calendar.php

```
 public function addEvents($events, array $customAttributes = [])
    {
        foreach ($events as $event) {
            $this->eventCollection->push($event, $customAttributes);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: `Calendar::addEvents($event_list);` this is a static call you need to make an instance first and then call it like `$instance->addEvents($event_list);`

Comment: could you show me how to change the code

Comment: i put an answer in with the suggested change

Comment: thank you very much, but after this change I have another problem "Too few arguments to function MaddHatter\LaravelFullcalendar\Calendar::__construct(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\kalendarz\app\Http\Controllers\EventsController.php on line 33 and exactly 2 expected"

Comment: The constructor of your calendar class requires parameters i do't know which ones but you should provide them. i updated my answer where you should provide them.

Comment: could you look here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54393022/laravel-full-calendar  have the same problem and almost the same code

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an instance of your calendar first

change:

```php
$calendar_details = Calendar::addEvents($event_list);
return view('events', compact('calendar_details') );
```

to:

```php
$calendar_details = new Calendar($your_construction_parameters);
$calendar_details->addEvents($event_list);
return view('events', compact('calendar_details'));
```